# What's this numeric notation called?

Tags: colors, hex

```
add(new CustomLabelField
("Please enter your credentials:", Color.WHITE, 0x999966, 0));
```

What is that 0x999966?

I want to place this color there so how can I convert it? I just need an online tool that will convert it for me but I don't even know what it's called! :D

[link for more info](http://www.color-hex.com/color/716eb3)

Thanks!

Edit: OK, so this is called a hexadecimal number, but I still don't know how to convert something like "#716eb3" to the notation accepted by the CustomLabelField constructor. Any help?

Comment: That's the hexadecimal notation for a RGB color. Google has a [list of online converters](http://www.google.com/#hl=en&source=hp&q=color+hex+to+decimal&aq=f&aqi=g1g-m1&aql=&oq=&gs_rfai=&pbx=1&fp=d331bd8e2d0de10c) that might interest you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Hexadecimal](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hexadecimal), as in, base 16.  If `0x999966` is indicating a color, then it's usually encoded such that each two hex digits encode a color (as RGB), so it's 0xRRGGBB.

Comment: I thought this was hexadecimal? #716eb3.

Comment: That notation is non-standard and is only used by HTML and related tools, AFAIK.  0x... is much more common in programming and computer science.  In either case, both are valid hex numbers.

Comment: `0x` or `#` as a prefix is just a convention to distinguish between hexadecimal and decimal (after all, it's only about conventions). This depends on the language. Some languages (typically, assembly) would use `999966h` for example. `0x` tends to be the notation used in *C* for example, whereas `#` would be used in *CSS* for colours.

Comment: To answer your other question, #716eb3 is exactly equivalent to 0x716eb3.

Answer (score 0):

Thats a number in `base 16` or `hexadecimal` number.

Comment: Isn't this hexadecimal? #716eb3 - how can I convert this #716eb3 to something like the code above?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like a [hexadecimal representation of a RGB](http://www.javascripter.net/faq/rgbtohex.htm). For example with `#716eb3`:

```
add(new CustomLabelField
("Please enter your credentials:", Color.WHITE, 0x716eb3, 0));
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like it might be in Java.

First, take the `substring` to remove the `#` prefix, then use `Integer.parseInt("9999966", 16)`: that's `parseInt` with the `radix` for the base (see `Integer` documentation). Something along these lines:

```
String colour = "#716eb3";
colour = colour.substring(1,colour.length()-1);
add(new CustomLabelField ("Please enter your credentials:",
     Color.WHITE, Integer.parseInt(colour,16), 0));
```

Comment: Note that this is only if you need to read the value dynamically, perhaps from a configuration file. If you want to hard-code the value, use `0x716eb3` directly, as others have already suggested.

Answer (score 0):

1. In many programming languages, numbers prefixed with 0 are octal and with 0x are hexadecimal.
2. Search for Hexadecimal to Decimal or Hexadecimal to RGB converters.

Answer (score 0):

If it's C#, the format expected by the CustomLabelField constructor is most likely `System.Drawing.Color` that uses the ARGB format.

“The color of each pixel is represented as a 32-bit number: 8 bits each for alpha, red, green, and blue (ARGB). The alpha component specifies the transparency of the color: 0 is fully transparent, and 255 is fully opaque. Likewise, an A value of 255 represents an opaque color. An A value from 1 through 254 represents a semitransparent color. The color becomes more opaque as A approaches 255.”

Converting the ARGB format into a `System.Drawing.Color` can be done as follows:

```
Color myColor = ColorTranslator.FromHtml("#FF999966");
```